# Error:(24, 0) Project with path ':wear' could not be found in project ':mobile'. Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I got the following error in Android Studio while creating project...

`Error:(24, 0) Project with path ':wear' could not be found in project ':mobile'.`

This is my build.gradle file code, I want to resolve this issue. Any help appreciated...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.user.usereventdemo"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
          }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
wearApp project(':wear')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your `settings.gradle`, is it including `:wear,`?

if you don't want codes of `wear`, then delete `:wear,` and `wearApp project(':wear')` in your `build.gradle`.

if you want, then you have to find codes of `wear`, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Under Gradle Scripts folder in Android Studio, locate "settings.gradle".
Open it and add ':wear' to the end of include statement.

It should look something like this:
include ':mobile', ':glass', ':wear'